# How to customize the page header of classicthesis in LyX

Tags: lyx, classicthesis

I use Lyx version of classicthesis: classicthesis-LyX-v4.2_biblatex_bibtex8.

Since I have long chapter and section titles, the Chapter and section headers go off page, as shown below.

I want to remove the titles and change them into Chapter i, Section j respectively. If this is not possible, then I want to have short titles instead of full titles.

I have not found any solutions for Lyx version (maybe just because I could not understand the solution for Latex version).Please provide step-by-step beginner-friendly solution.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, use the short title. That is what it is used for.

Comment: Could you please provide a step-by-step beginner-friendly solution? For example, how to locate the relevant code, and how to modify? Thx a lot. I have limited knowledge about Latex, that's why I use Lyx.

Comment: No idea, LyX is far too complex for me. I would have  to search for buttons. I don't use LyX nd stick to the more simple LaTeX.

Comment: Could you please teach me how to  locate the relevant code, and how to modify it in the LaTeX then? I know I need to fix them in the prewritten LaTeX document lying behind LyX anyway. Thx again.

Comment: Right click on your section heading and click on "Insert short title". Yes, it took me 10 minutes to figure out how to get a section and five more to actually find that button. I could have typed `\section[Mara]{Wombat}` 255 times by now.

Comment: It worked! Thx for your previous time! But do you have any idea for my first preference, that is, displaying as Chapter i, Section i.j on the header? This is optional though. Please try only if you are curious too.

Comment: Do you want to have `Chapter 1 Wombat` and `Section 1.1. Mara` or leave out the real titles? and just have Level+number?

Comment: Chapter I on the left page, Section 1.1 on the right page please. But your style of leve+number+short title is also interesting. So I do want to know both if you are interested in too.